# Does the Fencing Master feat stack with the 5th level extra attack?

Tags: feats, dnd-next-playtest

Do the extra attacks from the Fencing Master feat and the extra attack 5th level class benefit stack? Do I get to attack 3 times in one turn when having both of these?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes,** you get *can* get 3 attacks, but with a -5 penalty to each. Rarely worth it.

> Once on your turn when you use your action to make a melee attack with a finesse weapon, you **can** make one additional attack with that weapon, but all of the attacks that are part of the action take a –5 penalty to the attack roll.

At 5. level as a paladin you can make melee 2 attacks as an action. With this feat (wielding the right weapon), you can decide to make one additional attack, but in this case you take a -5 penalty to *all three* attacks. Doing so is rarely good for you, usually only worths it if you have advantage.*

The main attraction of Fencing Master from an optimization standpoint is the ability to parry the attack with a reaction.

Connecting to your [other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31856/can-i-make-a-worthwhile-one-handed-paladin/31858#31858) regarding an empty hand, even with this feat you benefit from a shield in your other hand.

*The mathematics of when is it better to attack 3 times with -5:

> 2 * H * D < 3 * (H-0.25) * D
>   2 * H < 3 * H - 0.75
>   2 * H + 0.75 < 3 * H
>   0.75 < H

Where H is your hit chance, and D is your damage. The 0.25 is the -5 converted from roll penalty to hit chance. As you can see, if you have a 0.75 chance (in other words you hit on a 6) it makes sense to make 3 attacks.

Comment: Oh, so taking the Fencing Master feat actually hurts the Extra Attack benefit by giving it a -5 penalty? Or do all extra attacks just naturally have -5?

Comment: **All** your attacks during the turn are hurt by -5. Extra attacks do not suffer such a penalty if you do not use the additional attack by Fencing Master.

Comment: Updated the answer with the clarification.

Comment: Wow, yeah definitely won't be using that part of the feat. That is absolutely horrible. Thanks for the help guys!